# Force Print to Landscape Using React Material UI and JSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to force to print to landscape in Material UI. The problem is this code doesn't
work

`'@page': { size: 'landscape' },`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        // '@page': { size: 'landscape' },
        '& .printIconButton': {
          display: 'none',
        },
        '& h4': {
          display: 'none',
        },
      },
    },
  }));
```